# Error when including Windows.h with glut.h

Tags: c, windows, opengl, glut

I'm doing a project using the GLUT library. Whenever I attempt to include Windows.h and compile/link, I get the following errors:

Error   1   error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdlib.h

Warning 2   warning C4985: 'exit': attributes not present on previous declaration.  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdlib.h

The conflict seems to relate to the "exit" function. I'm assuming that GLUT already defines an exit function, because I can call exit without including anything other than glut.h

I know other people have found a way around this, though. I've seen countless examples of GLUT programs that display a message box (which is why I am trying to include Windows.h). Does anyone else know what might resolve this?

Thanks